# fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: i "Passing argument 1 of objectAtIndexPath: makes pointer from integer without cast

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:0];

 for (int i; i<[sectionInfo numberOfObjects]; i++) {
  NSManagedObject *o = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:i];
  [dict setObject:[[o valueForKey:@"frontCard"] description] forKey:@"frontCard"];
  [dict setObject:[[o valueForKey:@"flipCard"] description] forKey:@"flipCard"];
 }
```

In this line

```
NSManagedObject *o = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:i];
```

i get this warning:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'objectAtIndexPath:' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Comment: You seem to be overwriting your dictionary values every time you loop through your managed objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`objectAtIndexPath:` expects an `NSIndexPath` object. You are passing an integer, which is incorrect.

You need to create an index path for a given row and section index, then pass it in. I don't know how you obtain your managed objects, but I'll just assume there's one row per section. If that's the case, do this to get each managed object within its section:

```
// It's also a good idea to initialize i in your loop and not just declare it
for (int i = 0; i<[sectionInfo numberOfObjects]; i++) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:i];
    NSManagedObject *o = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [dict setObject:[[o valueForKey:@"frontCard"] description] forKey:@"frontCard"];
    [dict setObject:[[o valueForKey:@"flipCard"] description] forKey:@"flipCard"];
}
```

Comment: thank you! but i already something else and my solution works too.